# Inline SVGs with Webpack, React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, webpack

I am trying to use SVG files for a React app I write to get used to it. I am using Webpack and Typescript for coding.
I am having a lot of trouble to import SVG files as inline SVG code in my components.

My SVG files are in a folder separate from my components folder and I would like to get the content of an SVG file from inside a component to place it inline.

I tried using `svg-inline-loader` and `react-svg-loader` but I can't manage to make any of them work. When I `console.log()` content of the variable in which I require my SVG file, I have some Javascript code, like a module-declaration, while I expect to find the SVG code instead.

Here is a simple component I am trying to use it in:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as classnames from "classnames";
import { ITaskProps } from "../interfaces";

export class Task extends React.Component<ITaskProps>
{
    render()
    {
        let outerClasses = classnames("rt-task", this.props.className);
        let Checkbox = require("svg-inline-loader!../asset/checkbox-unticked.svg");

        return (
            <span className={outerClasses}>
            { Checkbox }
                <span className="rt-checkbox-box">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="rt-task-checkbox" />
                </span>
                <label className="rt-checkbox-text" htmlFor="rt-task-checkbox">{this.props.text}</label>
            </span>
        )
    }
}
```

The result of the `console.log()` (which I removed from my code above) is this:

```
var _extends = Object.assign || function (target) { for (var i = 1; i <arguments.length; i++) { var source="arguments[i];" for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key]="source[key];" } } } return target; }; function _objectWithoutProperties(obj, keys) { var target="{};" for (var i in obj) { if (keys.indexOf(i)>= 0) continue; if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, i)) continue; target[i] = obj[i]; } return target; } import React from &quot;react&quot;; export default ((_ref) =&gt; { let { styles = {} } = _ref, props = _objectWithoutProperties(_ref, [&quot;styles&quot;]); return React.createElement( &quot;svg&quot;, _extends({ viewBox: &quot;0 0 100 100&quot;, xmlns: &quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&quot;, fillRule: &quot;evenodd&quot;, clipRule: &quot;evenodd&quot;, strokeLinejoin: &quot;round&quot;, strokeMiterlimit: &quot;1.414&quot; }, props), React.createElement(&quot;circle&quot;, { cx: &quot;50&quot;, cy: &quot;50&quot;, r: &quot;49&quot;, fill: &quot;transparent&quot;, stroke: &quot;#a6a6a6&quot;, strokeWidth: &quot;2&quot; }) ); });
```

I'm sure it is something trivial but I can't find how to do it and I've been looking for a solution since the beginning of the week...

Thank you :-)

Comment: Move `let Checkbox = require("svg-inline-loader!../asset/checkbox-unticked.svg");` outside of render next the rest of imports in the beginning of the file. `const Checkbox = require("svg-inline-loader!../asset/checkbox-unticked.svg");`

Comment: Change `{Checkbox}` to `<Checkbox />`

Comment: I moved the `require` and also tried using `Checkbox` as a node but in the first case I still have the same output and in the second case I have more errors because it tries to render something like `<var _extends ... />`

Comment: I tried it in `create-react-app` and didn't work for me either -.-. Sorry.

Comment: You can render it as the `src` of an `img`.
`import checkbox from './<path_to_svg>'`;

Inside render.          
`<img src={checkbox} />

Comment: I would really like inline SVGs because if I understood well, then you can manipulate them afterwards